# How to run cronjob without command in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cron

At my current host, i can only set cron jobs with URL and not with command.
Is there a way to run the **Magento 2 cron jobs inside a php** or **sh** file that i can run it over a URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify `.htaccess` to allow it, you can run `pub/cron.php`.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/pub/.htaccess#L207

Comment: Ok i have test it but it won't work. I became some uncaught errors.

Comment: Add the errors here and someone might be able to help you.